# combine kineticjs and pixastic to apply image effect

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs, pixastic

I'm trying to use some features from the pixastic libary and combine it with kineticjs. One of which is to apply the sepia effect in pixastic to an image created with kineticjs.

I have a jsfiddle setup here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SkVJu/28/

I thought the following would work:

```
function sepia() {
    Pixastic.process(darth, "sepia");
    layer.draw();
}
```

but the image just stays the same. Have i missed something or is this not even possible to combine the both libraries together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you can't apply a Pixastic function directly onto a `Kinetic.Image` object, as it is slightly different than a regular image object.

Alternatively, you need to grab the original source of the image, then you can run the Pixastic effects on that image, and then `set` the Kinetic.Image object with the new affected image after.

```
function sepia() {
  var sepia = Pixastic.process(darth.attrs.image, "sepia");
  darth.setImage(sepia);
  layer.draw();
}
```

Here's the full code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/Fv64z/)

**Note:** You'll have to run this on your local server, as it won't work on jsfiddle (the **pixastic** library can't be loaded as an external resource, without a CDN host)

**2nd Note:** You had to declare `var layer` outside of the `imageObj.onload` function, or else your `sepia()` function could not access the `layer` from inside the `imageObj.onload`. You can see how I did it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks so much for the help, i was playing around for hours trying to solve it!

Comment: I tried this and I get the following error when I'm trying to apply the effect on a btn click  " Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. "